# How to average the year MM-DD-YYYY string of all rows in SQL BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

**Context**

This table was created in BigQuery from a Firestore database export storage bucket.

**Goal**

I am trying to create a query that averages the year of all my users in my user's table.

users table:

```
uid    username    birthday
XXXX   user1       04-04-2004
```

**Attempts**

```
SELECT 
    AVG( FORMAT_DATETIME("%y", birthday) )
FROM `bucket-96863.sqlQueries.users`
WHERE birthday != 'null' limit 10

-- Error: No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATETIME for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: FORMAT_DATETIME(STRING, DATETIME); FORMAT_DATETIME(STRING, TIMESTAMP, [STRING]) at [2:10]
```

```
SELECT 
    AVG( CAST( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthday) AS int64 ) )
FROM `bucket-96863.sqlQueries.users`
WHERE birthday != 'null' limit 10

-- Error: No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM STRING. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME) at [2:16]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider below

```
select avg(extract(year from cast(birthday as date format 'MM-DD-YYYY')))
from `bucket-96863.sqlQueries.users`
```

Comment: Perfect, I also understand the `EXTRACT` function better now. I didn't think to cast the argument before extracting it. Clever, thanks for the insight.